# Joomla Component Dynamic Custom Field based on other Field Value

Tags: ajax, database, joomla, field, components

I am creating a new Joomla Component. I am able to create custom fields for the component backend forms - but I am not able to create Dynamic Custom Fields.

What I would like to do is have a field that is dynamical populated based on the value of a previous field. The easiest way to explain this is the simple country,state,city breakdown.

```
Field 1 = Country
Field 2 = State (Based on what the user selected as as Country in Field 1)
Field 3 = City (Based on what the user selected as State in Field 2)
```

The fields would of course need to be refreshed, reset as the user picks a different country etc.

The data to populate the fields would also all need to come from a database based on the previous fields value.

I am guessing this needs to be done via ajax or javascript or something? But wondering if there is an official way? Especially since there are database calls involved.

Please let me know if there is anything I can explain better..
David

Comment: There isn't any official way of doing this. You would need to create an ajax call that loads the 2nd selector based on what input was selected in the first.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reply! I ended up just creating text fields but then validating the input to make sure the values added are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just creating text fields but then validating the input to make sure the values added are correct.